# Codeigniter loading library after session is set

Tags: codeigniter, session, pdo, sqlite, static-libraries

I am using codeigniter with sqlite and I have created a new library for connecting the sqlite database. The sqlite database will connect only if the session is set.

**LIBRARY (userdb)**

```
$CI =& get_instance();
    if( $CI->session->userdata('user') ){
    $userId = $CI->session->userdata('user');
    $this->conDb = new PDO("sqlite:" . BASEPATH . "sqlitedb/" . $userId . "/data.db");
    }else{    
    $userId = '';   
    }
```

And I execute queries by using `$query = $this->userdb->query($sql);`

It works fine but the problem is that query only works if the page is refreshed after session is created otherwise it returns `Call to a member function query() on a non-object` error.

**CONTROLLER**

```
   $sessiondata = array('user' => $userid);
   $this->session->set_userdata($sessiondata);

   $insert = $this->user_model->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this seems legit, if you set your userdata while the page/controller is loading it means that the librairies and other assets have been loaded already.  So when your userdb library is loaded there is no sessions set yet.

You have two ways to fix this : Try to Load your library after loading your controller but for a db library this would be better to be in your config file so that it is auto loaded.

The other way would be to reload or redirect your current PAGE after the session isset. So that you can use your db library

Hope that helps You

NwK